# php - How To Convert 1 day To Seconds

Tags: php, string, time, intervals, seconds

I am creating a form to set publish interval and want to sum all of the submitted values into seconds. The form consist of fields to determine seconds, minutes, hours, day and so on.

I am collecting the submitted values to string by giving date attributes, like second, minute etc.

**For example:**

$second second

$minute minute

$hour hour

So if user input 1 in input field to determine the interval in `day` and 30 in `minute`, then my code will convert it to string `1 day` and `30 minute`.

**My questions:**

1- How can I convert `1 day` and `30 minute` string into seconds so they can be summed up into correct seconds.

I tried to use `strtotime()` but it returns a very large number of seconds and `date()` but it return too small number.

2- Is there a simple function like `strtotime()` and `date()` that can do string to second conversion correctly?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` with a second parameter, like following:

```
strtotime('1 day 30 second', 0);
```

This will give you `86430`, which is the number of seconds in 1 day and 30 seconds.

(If the second parameter is omitted, the current timestamp (i.e. `time()`) is used to add what is specified in the string, which leads to the big number.)

Comment: Awesome..! That's really a neat solution!

Comment: Note, that the main magic here is the **`0`** used for `baseTimestamp` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$day = 1;
$hour = 1;
$minute = 1;
$second = 0;
$second += (($day * 24 + $hour) * 60 + $minute) * 60;
```