# Convert Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds to an integer

Tags: php, date, date-arithmetic

I can convert an int to days, hours, minutes and seconds, but what is the calculation to reverse that and convert back to seconds?

Here's what I have for the first conversion:

```
<?php
$seconds = 12345;
$days = floor ($seconds / 60 / 60 / 24);
$hours = floor ($seconds / 60 / 60) % 24;
$minutes = floor ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$seconds = $seconds % 60;
?>
```

Comment: days usually have 24 hours. and so 24*60 minuten. and os 24*60*60 seconds. (except days where daylightsavingtime starts). So where one way you use / ,now use *

Comment: I believe you can use `strtotime` and it will change it to a timestamp (int)

Comment: @asa-carter Are you kidding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20596966/4934273

Comment: but question remains, why? What is the goal of this. Wouldn't there be another route to solve your problem, as this seconds issue seems not to be the optimal way

Comment: @IvoP Time is stored as an int the database, but I need to split it into D, H, M, S for an API, and then save back to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$total = ($days * 24 * 60 * 60) + ($hours * 60 * 60) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$total = ($days * 24 * 60 * 60) + ($hours * 60 * 60) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;
```

Comment: The parentheses is not needed. In (normal) math multiply goes before addition.